# Python - Send a request for each item in a list with dynamic values

Tags: python, loops, python-requests

I'm currently working with the UPS Package Tracking API to send a tracking number via a POST request that the API receives and sends back a JSON response with information about the package.

Currently, I just got the actual request working with a single tracking number value using several nested dictionaries, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it send the request with a different tracking number each time.

Code below:

```
trk = ["tracknbr1", "tracknbr2", "tracknbr3"]

data = {"UPSSecurity" : {
        "UsernameToken" : {
            "Username" : nme,
            "Password" : pwd
        },
        "ServiceAccessToken" : {
            "AccessLicenseNumber" : aln
        },
    },
    "TrackRequest" : {
        "Request" : {
            "RequestOption" : 1,
            "TransactionReference" : {
                "CustomerContext" : ""
            },
        },
        "InquiryNumber" : trk
    }
    }

req = requests.post("https://wwwcie.ups.com/rest/Track", json=data)
print (req.text)
```

"**InquiryNumber**" is where the tracking number is stored inside the request.

*(Apologies if most of the code shown is unnecessary to the problem, thought it would make my issue easier to understand.)*

So, right now it is only sending the request for the first item in the list, and then printing out the response.

I am trying to figure out a way to have the request loop through each item in the list, sending the request with the next tracking number each time.

I've tried several different methods with `for` loops, but I cannot get it to iterate through the actual values inside the list for each request.

There may be an obvious solution I am not seeing, as I am more or less just starting with Python. Let me know what you guys think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reusing `trk` variable for different things (for a `list` and then for a single `InquiryNumber`) in your example.

```
import requests


nme = 'your_username'
pwd = 'your_password'
aln = 'your_accesslicensenumber'

tracking_numbers = ["tracknbr1", "tracknbr2", "tracknbr3"]

for trk in tracking_numbers:
    data = {"UPSSecurity" : {
            "UsernameToken" : {
                "Username" : nme,
                "Password" : pwd
            },
            "ServiceAccessToken" : {
                "AccessLicenseNumber" : aln
            },
        },
        "TrackRequest" : {
            "Request" : {
                "RequestOption" : 1,
                "TransactionReference" : {
                    "CustomerContext" : ""
                },
            },
            "InquiryNumber" : trk
        }
        }

    response = requests.post("https://wwwcie.ups.com/rest/Track", json=data)
    print(response.json())
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much. Funnily enough, I just thought of placing the entire JSON request inside a loop before I saw your response, but I didn't even think about how I can't use `trk` twice. Thanks!