# Looping through GET request with multiple parameters of different length

Tags: python, get-request

Follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58323668/call-api-for-each-element-in-list) I asked a few days ago:

I still have to call the API for every element of the list but now I need some additional parameters. I have a list of values for every parameter with different lengths. Every customerId has multiple keywordIds and areaIds (which always have the same length for a given customer). 
Every customer has different keywords. So for example the first five keyword IDs belong to the first ID in customerlist. The next three keyword IDs to the second ID in customerlist, and so on.
I tried it with `zip`, but I only get the first entry for the first keyword of the first customerid instead of all entries for every keyword of every customer (in this case the information for the keyword 1172646 and the area 29010 from the customer 803818 where isareafirst = false).

```
import json
import requests
import itertools

API_BASEURL = "https://exampleurl.com/"
API_TOKEN = "abc"
HEADERS = {'content-type' : 'application/json',
           'Authorization': API_TOKEN }


customerlist = [803818, 803808, 803803,803738,803730]
keywordlist = [1172646, 1218994,1218992 1218993,1218992, 1218995, 1218993, 1173529, 1235569,1187456,1187455,1187453]
arealist = [29010, 28882, 28882, 28882, 28882, 28882, 28882, 28882, 31237,31237, 31237,31237]
isareafirstlist = [False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False,False, False, False]



def get_history(endpoint):
        responses = []
        for i,j,k,l in zip(customerlist,keywordlist, arealist, isareafirstlist):
            api_endpoint = endpoint
            params = {'customerid' : i,
                      'keywordid' : j,
                      'areaid' : k,
                      'isareafirst': l}
            response = requests.get(f"{API_BASEURL}/{api_endpoint}",
                                 params = params,
                                 headers = HEADERS)
            res = json.loads(response.text)
            responses.append(res)
        return (responses)
```

I also tried `itertools.zip_longest`, but this just gives me errors where I received empty lists with `zip`

```
def get_history(endpoint):
    responses = []
    for i,j,k,l in itertools.zip_longest(customerlist,keywordlist, arealist, isareafirstlist):
        api_endpoint = endpoint
        params = {'customerid' : i,
                  'keywordid' : j,
                  'areaid' : k,
                  'isareafirst': l}
        response = requests.get(f"{API_BASEURL}/{api_endpoint}",
                             params = params,
                             headers = HEADERS)
        res = json.loads(response.text)
        responses.append(res)
    return (responses)
```

So how can I loop through the API with every combination that is possible?

Comment: Try `list.itertools.product(*list_of_lists)` where `list_of_lists` is the list of `[customerlist, keywordlist, arealist, isareafirstlist]`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this implementation help?

```
import itertools
customerlist = [803818, 803808, 803803,803738,803730]
keywordlist = [1172646, 1218994,1218992, 1218993,1218992, 1218995, 1218993, 1173529, 1235569,1187456,1187455,1187453]
arealist = [29010, 28882, 28882, 28882, 28882, 28882, 28882, 28882, 31237,31237, 31237,31237]
isareafirstlist = [False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False,False, False]
list_of_lists = [customerlist, keywordlist, arealist, isareafirstlist]
for _ in itertools.product(*list_of_lists):
    print _
```